# is there a more efficient way of comparing two variables obtained from a db?

Tags: php, mysql

This works but is there a shorter(more efficient) way of doing this?
code compares 2 numbers. One is from the most recent record, the other is from 7 records down.

```php
$sql5="SELECT market_cap_rank FROM intelligence WHERE id='$thiscoin' order by day desc limit 0,1";
$row5 =  mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($conn, $sql5));
$newest = $row5[0];
$sql6="SELECT market_cap_rank FROM intelligence WHERE id='$thiscoin' order by day desc limit 6,1"; 
$row6 =  mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($conn, $sql6));
$oldest = $row6[0];
$rankdiff=$oldest-$newest;
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're doing this in 2 queries? That will be the bulk of the overhead here.

Comment: *code compares 2 numbers.* I see that the code substracts them only, and no comparing.

Comment: Use simple `SELECT (second SELECT text) - (first SELECT text) AS difference`. For MySQL 8+ you may use window function which will simplify the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both queries in to a single one avoiding round trips to DB server.

Assign ranks to each of the 7 rows after order by with the help of SQL variable. Now, `sum()` all values by filtering the rows which have rank either `1` or `7`.
If `rank = 1`, add it's negative state.

As a side note, if `$thiscoin` is coming from user, you can better make parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

**Query:**

```
select sum(if(rank = 1,-mcr,mcr)) as diff_mcr
from (
    SELECT  @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,market_cap_rank as mcr
    FROM intelligence,(select @rank := 0) r  
    WHERE id = '$thiscoin' 
    order by day desc limit 0,7
) derived
where rank = 1 or rank = 7
```

**Code:**

This would simply be

```
$rankdiff = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))[0];
```

Comment: I don't think that query is equivalent to what they're doing. The value of `max(mcr))` (i.e. the largest value for `market_cap_rank` in the first 7 entries) is not necessarily the value of 7th mcr as ordered by day.

Comment: @TheGentleman order by day will happen first and then the limit clause applies.

Comment: @vivek-23 yes, but you are "Max'ing" a different variable than you are ordering. Consider the data set S = [20,40,70,30,15, 35, 60] which we can say is ordered by date.  `max(S)` = 70, while the 7th element of S is 60

Comment: @TheGentleman First sorting happens in the query. So `S = [70,60,40,35,30,20,15]`. Now limit `0,7` gets top 7 entries out of it , so it is again `S = [70,60,40,35,30,20,15]`, and `max - min` gives `70-15=55`.

Comment: @TheGentleman See this for more clarity http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa2fd2/4

Comment: @TheGentleman The 7th element is actually after sorting and not it's initial position.

Comment: @vivek-23, precisely, you just demonstrated my point. you are assuming that they are querying the same column that they ordering by, which is explicitly incorrect. We can see from the question that they are querying `market_cap_rank` and ordering by `day`. See this fiddle which is a more accurate representation of the scheme: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f396/1

Comment: @TheGentleman  Thanks for correcting. I completely overlooked. Fixed it now.

Comment: @vivek-23 no worries, really like that new query too!

Comment: @vivek-23 I had no idea sql could do such a thing! This helps a lot as it's an operation applied to 500 rows on a page, but it's just for me, no other visitors.

Comment: @vivek-23  I think the point TheGentleman makes is correct because all the results come out positive and some of them should be negative. it is the 7th result minus the 1st result. It sorts by the day field which is number which looks like 20200801 so the highest number is always the most recent day.  So the 7th result is always 7 days ago and the 1st result is always today.

Comment: @TheGentleman see above plus i've filled this one with real data. the answer should be -46 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10c5a3/2

Comment: @jdoe For your demo data http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10c5a3/7